# Why can't Loaders be non-static inner classes?

Tags: android, android-loadermanager, android-loader

When I try to use a non-static inner `Loader` class, I get the following runtime error:

> Object returned from onCreateLoader must not be a non-static inner
>   member class

What's the point of this restriction?

Comment: If I had to guess, the `Loader` itself may survive a configuration change, at least for a while. Usually, the "must not be a non-static inner class" restriction is when we are concerned about memory leaks. That being said, I don't know *why* the `Loader` would survive a configuration change (though the data it loads should survive) and so I don't know that this is the actual rationale.

Comment: Yeah I considered memory leaks but I don't understand why it's so strictly enforced when a warning would suffice, unless the internal workings of LoaderManager are guaranteed to cause a leak.

Answer (score 5):

As noted in [this blog post on loaders](https://medium.com/google-developers/making-loading-data-on-android-lifecycle-aware-897e12760832), they are specifically designed to survive rotation changes (which usually result in the activity being destroyed and recreated). As non-static inner classes contain an implicit reference to their containing instance (i.e., the inner class would have a reference to the first Activity), this is guaranteed to create a memory leak on any configuration change.

Comment: please, thus in `onCreateLoader()` extending e.g. `loadInBackground()` method as new inner class like:
`new CursorLoader(mActivity) {
@Override
public Cursor loadInBackground() 
{ ... }`

creates a reference to the Activity too?

Comment: @GPack - as seen in the [source of Loader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/Loader.java#103) as well as [mentioned in the blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/making-loading-data-on-android-lifecycle-aware-897e12760832#df97), the Loader doesn't use the supplied `Context` directly, but uses the application Context exactly to prevent keeping a reference to the Activity.

Comment: my question was not about the use of "mActivity" context, it was about extending in Activity/Fragment the CursorLoader class by a inner class and its consequence. 
I opened a question [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/q/36957243/4274296) if you want reply , thanks

Comment: @GPack - yeah, that's an inner class and therefore a memory leak.

Comment: ok this is very clear for me, while instead I dont understand how LoaderManager can retain the reference to the callbacks (got by `getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this`);) without leaking the Activity/Fragment

Comment: It doesn't retain the `LoaderCallbacks`. Just the `Loader` itself.